# How to recieve response from server in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {
        NSLog("Received response\(response)")
        myResponseData = NSMutableData()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
     myResponseData.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
     NSLog("\(myResponseData)");
     let strData = NSString(data: myResponseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
     print("Body: \(strData)", terminator: "")
```

How can we receive a response from a server and according to that set an alert message, like if the status is success we have to show an alert message

Answer (score 0):

An easy, but not so scalable solution is:

1. - create a subclass of NSURLRequest. Override the initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method and make this class its own delegate. Pass NO to super as last argument.
2. - Implement the delegate methods.
3. - Create an NSURLRequest
4. - create an instance of your subclass using the NSURLRequest you just created.
5. - Call -start on you connection. Make sure your connection is a property if some class that outlives the connection, otherwise the connection will be deallocated before it has a chance to do anything.

Note that NSURConnection is deprecated in favor of NSURLSession.

Comment: In which delegate method I should receive the response? Can you explain briefly?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you more details. If you need actual code, you can find loads of examples online.